# Mobile App Server doesn't receive PushAsync calls from client when App Service Authentication is turned On

Tags: azure, azure-mobile-services

I'm using Azure Mobile App Service for the Mobile App Backend/Server.

The client can insert items into the remote table when the App Service Authentication is Off. (I use portal.azure to turn App Service Auth on and off).

However, turning on the App Service Authentication seems to prevent PushAsync from calling the associated Post method in the table controller. I know because I put in code that would write to the App Logs whenever a request enters a method in the table controller.

When the App Service Authentication is Off, i can see that the Trace print code in PostItem wrote to the App Logs and then followed by GetAll Trace print code.

When the App Service Auth is On, the Trace print code in PostItem method didnt write which should mean PostItem was not called. The GetAll Trace print code still wrote to the App Logs, however.

The user is authenticated since the user is logged in using MobileServiceClient.LoginAsync

Does anyone know how i can debug and/or solve this problem?

**UPDATE 1**

Here's the table controller

```
[Authorize]
public class ItemController : TableController<Item>
{
    protected override void Initialize(HttpControllerContext controllerContext)
    {
        base.Initialize(controllerContext);
        MobileServiceContext context = new MobileServiceContext();
        DomainManager = new EntityDomainManager<Item>(context, Request);
    }

    // GET tables/Item
    public async Task<IQueryable<Item>> GetAllItem()
    //public IQueryable<Item> GetAllItem()
    {
        // Initialize variable
        string userGUID = "";

        // Retrieve credentials of requester
        AzureActiveDirectoryCredentials userCreds = await User.GetAppServiceIdentityAsync<AzureActiveDirectoryCredentials>(Request);

        System.Diagnostics.Trace.TraceInformation("Get All Item Controller");

        // If usercreds is not null, retrieve requester's GUID
        if (userCreds != null) userGUID = userCreds.ObjectId;

        //Retrieve items that match user's aad id AND item that is not deleted
        var query = Query().Where(item => !item.Deleted && item.RequesterId.Equals(userGUID, System.StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));

        // return query;
        return Query();
    }

    // GET tables/Item/48D68C86-6EA6-4C25-AA33-223FC9A27959
    public SingleResult<Item> GetItem(string id)
    {
        return Lookup(id);
    }

    // PATCH tables/Item/48D68C86-6EA6-4C25-AA33-223FC9A27959
    public Task<Item> PatchItem(string id, Delta<Item> patch)
    {
         return UpdateAsync(id, patch);
    }

    // POST tables/Item
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> PostItem(Item item)
    {

        System.Diagnostics.Trace.TraceInformation("Post Item Controller");

        AzureActiveDirectoryCredentials userCreds = await User.GetAppServiceIdentityAsync<AzureActiveDirectoryCredentials>(Request);

        // Set requester id for item
        item.RequesterId = userCreds.ObjectId;

        // Save item to db
        Item current = await InsertAsync(item);

        return CreatedAtRoute("Tables", new { id = current.Id }, current);
    }

    // DELETE tables/Item/48D68C86-6EA6-4C25-AA33-223FC9A27959
    public Task DeleteItem(string id)
    {
         return DeleteAsync(id);
    }
}
```

**UPDATE 2**

In PostItem, i put the code which retrieves requester credentials in a try-catch.

```
// POST tables/Item
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> PostItem(Item item)
{
    // Initialize variable
    string userId = "";

    System.Diagnostics.Trace.TraceInformation("Post Item Controller");


    AzureActiveDirectoryCredentials userCreds = null;

    // Retrieve credentials of requester
    try
    {
        userCreds = await User.GetAppServiceIdentityAsync<AzureActiveDirectoryCredentials>(Request);
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Trace.TraceInformation(e.Message);
    }

    if (userCreds != null) System.Diagnostics.Trace.TraceInformation("user creds is null");
    else System.Diagnostics.Trace.TraceInformation("user creds is not null");

    // If usercreds is not null, retrieve requester's id
    if (userCreds != null) userId = userCreds.ObjectId;

    // Set requester id for item
    item.RequesterId = userId;
    // Save item to db
    Item current = await InsertAsync(item);
    return CreatedAtRoute("Tables", new { id = current.Id }, current);
}
```

**The error message i got:** "The IPrincipal's Claims must contain an 'iss' Claim."

Comment: What is the backend written in?  Node.js or ASP.NET?  Can you share the backend table controller code?

Comment: A fiddler trace for the failed connection may also yield important debugging information.

Comment: it's written in C# and i've posted the code in the update. also, i got an error when i put the suspected offending code in a try catch. This was the error message: "The IPrincipal's Claims must contain an 'iss' Claim."

Comment: Thanks for the update.  How are you logging in within your app?  Also, can you give the run-down of how you have set up Authentication?  Did you use the Settings -> Authentication / Authorization link or the Mobile Authentication link (which is deprecated and needs to be removed since it isn't supported by the newer SDKs)

Comment: That exception is thrown if you have an X-ZUMO-AUTH token but that token does not contain the 'iss' claim. That seems to indicate you're getting an incorrect token when you log in. On the client, LoginAsync returns you a MobileServiceUser that has a MobileServiceAuthenticationToken (if using C#) property that contains your token. Can you grab that value after you log in and put it in the 'Encoded' text box at http://jwt.io and see what it shows in the 'Payload' box on the 'Decoded' side?

Comment: @brettsam i use the MobileServiceClient.CurrentUser for retrieving the token in the app. But since you metioned the MobileServiceUser returned by LoginAsync, thats the one i used to retrieve the token for decodin in jwt.io. And here's the payload: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/3c4382e7c1bffcbb5495

Comment: @brettsam since you mentioned the MobileServiceUser returned by LoginAsync. Can you answer this question of mine regarding the difference between MobileServiceUser returned by LoginAsync and the MobileServiceClient.CurrentUser after LoginAsyc? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35592818/is-the-token-in-mobileserviceclient-currentuser-after-loginasync-and-token-of-mo

Comment: @AdrianHall I turn on App Logging in portal.azure and set the level at information. After that, I use System.Diagnostics.Trace.TraceInformation("message") in the server code. Yup, i use the former i.e. Settings -> Authentication / Authorization. Configuration of AAD is done by someone else though. What do you mean about "Mobile Authentication link"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a theory -- try creating your `MobileServiceClient` with 'https' instead of 'http'. The authentication requires that 'iss' and 'aud' match the URL of the current request exactly and I suspect that your requests are actually not authenticating properly.

But that doesn't explain how the request got through if you had `[Authorize]` on your Controller for all of your testing -- was that present the whole time? I would expect your calls from the client to get a 401 if the Request was not validated.

Comment: thanks. it now works. woot! tbh, i no longer remember if the controller has [Authorize] when i was testing PostItem. what i do know is that with [Authorize] and the use of "http://(url)", the GetAllItems still work.